# What effect does the wrong T-V pronoun have on truth-value?

Tags: semantics, pronouns, lexical-semantics

Suppose someone uses the wrong T-V pronoun in a sentence, e.g. a French person uses "tu" instead of "vous". Is that considered to render the sentence (a) false or (b) without truth-value? If neither, how is the semantic distinction between T and V pronouns characterised?

(I've had to stray from my lane to ask this question, so please be gentle.)

Comment: Note that in languages where T/V reuses a pronoun that has another function, e.g. in French where *vous* is also 2cp, you could introduce ambiguity in the interpretation. Not, of course, that that would change the speaker's intended truth values (presumably they only have one in mind), but a different set of truth conditions might be imparted to the hearer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The choice of register (how respectful you're being) is generally considered a *pragmatic* matter, not a *semantic* one. In other words, it could potentially make an utterance *infelicitous*, but cannot make it *untrue*.

For an English example, if your boss asks you to come into work while you're sick, saying "fuck that and fuck you, I'm sick as shit" isn't saying anything untrue, but is generally inappropriate for the circumstances. You've violated a pragmatic constraint (the social expectation that you'll use a certain register when talking to your boss), but not a semantic one; you'd reasonably expect your boss to say "that's inappropriate", but not "that's not true".

Comment: Forget respectfulness for a moment. If "tu" and "vous" convey different information about your relative social statuses, is it still a pragmatic matter rather than a semantic one?

Comment: @Remster Those are two contradictory statements. Information about your relative social statuses is _semantically irrelevant except as regards respectfulness_. It doesn’t change anything about how true or untrue what you say is. Assuming you’re only speaking to one person, the choice between _tu_ and _vous_ is predicated on the level of respectfulness and/or distance your relative social statuses entail (within the scope of the setting and context your particular conversation is happening in).

Comment: I don't think I was contradicting myself - it's possible for two people to have different social statuses without either of them caring about it. That said, I get the point.

Comment: @Remster But whether or not you care about differing social statuses is _also_ pragmatics, not semantics. It wasn’t perhaps a contradiction as such, but if we’re only talking about the semantic (not pragmatic) contents of an utterance, forgetting about respectfulness automatically makes social status irrelevant, because the only place where social status plays any part at all in semantics is the role it plays in selecting an appropriate level of respect (where pragmatics feeds into semantics). The speaker’s beliefs about the world can affect what they say, but whether what they say is true.

Comment: @Remster Unfortunately, the line between semantics and pragmatics is not always an easy one to draw. I would say register is distinctly pragmatic, not semantic, specifically _because_ it doesn't affect the truth conditions: "I'm sick as shit" isn't an _untrue_ thing to say to your boss, it's just an _inappropriate_ one.

Comment: @Remster you could probably say that a T/V pronoun carries a presupposition or so regarding social status. That presupposition can be true or untrue, making the utterance felicitous or not. But as a presupposition (or so) it does not figure in the semantic composition to obtain the main at-issue meaning. For instance, the presupposition is unchanged under negation, and you cannot say “hey, that’s not true” but can say “hey wait a minute”. So you can use truth values in the analysis if you want, but they won’t compose.

Comment: [Correction to my comment above: “The speaker’s beliefs about the world can affect what they say, but **not** whether what they say is true.” Rather crucial negation missing.]

Comment: The semantic difference lies in the conjugation. The difference in conjugation leads to the social meaning. Neither tu or vous is related to the truth value of any statement at all.

Comment: The way you would get a sentence with a truth value would be to talk *about* the pronoun. E.g. "I should use *tu* when I address my boss." would likely be false.

Comment: I would think it might be useful to recognize situations where a choice of pronoun might change the semantic meaning of a sentence.  For example, if a group of familiars approach and a member of the group says something while speaking for the group, a sentence using "tu" would unambiguously be referring to the speaker, while a sentence using "vous" could be interpreted as more likely referring to the group as a whole.

Comment: @supercat Who the addressee(s) of the sentence is/are, does not change its meaning. How can being more polite or less polites via pronouns change the basic meaning? It would not.

Comment: @Lambie Well, the truth _values_ can change depending on the addressee. "You are male" is true when addressing some people and false when addressing others, because the referent of "you" is different.

Comment: @supercat That’s not a T/V distinction, though, but a singular/plural distinction. The T/V distinction takes its name from a case that overloads a plural pronoun to make a polite singular, but they are separate things. Better examples with 2p verb are Dutch (sg. _jij_ vs _u_, pl. _jullie_ vs _u_) or Kazakh (sg. _sen_ vs _siz_, pl. _sender_ vs _sizler_); or with 3p verbs, Hungarian (sg. _te_ vs _ön_, pl. _ti_ vs _önök_), Italian/Spanish/Portuguese (sg. _tu_ vs _Lei/usted/você_, pl. _voi/vos[otros]_ vs _Loro/ustedes/vocês_) or Polish (sg. _ty_ vs _pan[i]_, pl. _wy_ vs _państwo/pan[ow]ie_).

Comment: @Draconis Truth value is not semantic meaning. Tu es intelligent. Vous êtes intelligents. The T or V pronoun *does not change the meaning*. It changes only the social acceptance of the utterance.

Comment: @Lambie See the question, where the OP asks about truth values specifically by name. "Meaning" is a term with a lot of different definitions, but "truth value" is one of those definitions, and that's clearly the one the question is about.

Comment: @Draconis **Truth value comes from logic and math, not from linguistics**. How many ways can we explain that? The question is not valid linguistically, only logically.

Comment: @Lambie Formal semantics is traditionally considered a part of linguistics.

Comment: I doubt Tarski would agree with that: The semantic conception of truth, which is related in different ways to both the correspondence and deflationary conceptions, is due to work by Polish logician Alfred Tarski. Tarski, in "On the Concept of Truth in Formal Languages" (1935), attempted to formulate a new **theory of truth in order to resolve the liar paradox**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_theory_of_truth But why go on and on with this when Tu versus Vous is simple not affected by the concept of truth value as **generally understood**?

Comment: Also, the question says "what effect does **the wrong T or V**" have on the truth value? What is the "wrong *tu* or *vous*? That is meaningless. There is only one tu or vous in the language.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: None whatsover.

- Tu es allé au marché hier.
- Vous êtes allé au marché hier.

Both can be true or false or either can. One is the French vous form aka polite form and the other is the tu form aka familiar form. The first shows more social distance from the person and the second is more familiar.

- The semantic difference concerns only the conjugation of the verb aller in the preterite*. Unlike English, tu and vous take different verb endings.
- Tu es allé au marché hier.
- Vous êtes allé au marché hier.

You went to the market yesterday.
Both of which are **you** English.

Comment: Ah, so if I were to say "Tu es allé au marché hier" to a teacher (say), it would be considered true (assuming the teacher had been to the market yesterday) but rude.

Comment: @Remster You would be being rude, whether it's true or false.